# Laravel Totem no firing tasks.`

Tags: php, laravel, cron

My tasks run when I execute them directly on the the dashboard but on when they are scheduled. But the scheduled command on Kernel they are running instead.

I am running php 7.2
Laravel 5.6.*
Totem 3.2

Comment: i too have same problem, did you find any solution

Comment: No not yet. Will write it here when I find it.

Comment: check out my answer bellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel will not load new crons added in totem unless you do:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

That did the trick :D